# SSRS 2008 R2 - Is it Possible to Create Parameters for Table Views

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, view

I have created a view in the database and am I want a report generated from that view. The view is not part of the Cube so the conventional parameter option in the dataset does not exist. So is there any way that I can pass parameter for a view in SSRS. I tried adding parameters and filters in dataset but the column names in view do not get accepted as a parameter.  Please let me know if this is possible or what is the alternative.

Comment: Try wrapping the view in a stored procedure or query.

Answer (score 0):

Views can not take parameters. You can, however, create a [table-valued function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that can act very much like a view.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
AS
  SELECT col FROM dbo.table;
```

Could be re-written as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction(@dt DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN (SELECT col FROM dbo.table -- or even dbo.MyView
    WHERE date_col = @dt);
```

Or, of course, your report could simply point to a stored procedure, which in turn uses parameters to guide the WHERE clause against the base table or the view...